# ODP.NET && Entity Framework 'Index was outside the bounds of the array' Exception

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, odp.net

I'm using oracle 12 c with entity framework 6 depending on oracle data provider for .net (ODP.net).When I'm trying to add result binding for computed columns in insert procedure I'm getting '**Index was outside the bounds of the array**' exception.

Here is scenario details:
Using oracle 12 c I've created this table which contains 'commision' as computed column (vrtual)

```
CREATE TABLE emp(
  id          NUMBER,
  first_name  VARCHAR2(10),
  last_name   VARCHAR2(10),
  salary      NUMBER(9,2),
  commision   NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS (ROUND(salary*0.1,2)) VIRTUAL,
  CONSTRAINT employees_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

After that I've created an insert procedure which returns the inserted record at the end:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sprocEMP_INSERT 
  (    
    first_name_P    EMP.first_name%TYPE     ,
    last_name_P     EMP.last_name%TYPE      ,
    salary_P        EMP.salary%TYPE         ,
    curParam OUT SYS_REFCURSOR

  )    
IS 
   RECORD_ID EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE;
BEGIN 
    RECORD_ID := EMPLOYEES_SEQ.NEXTVAL; 
    INSERT INTO HR.EMPLOYEES
        (
          id          ,
          first_name  ,
          last_name   ,
          salary        
        )  
    VALUES 
        (
          RECORD_ID   ,
          first_name_P,
          last_name_P ,
          salary_P
        );  
    COMMIT;
    OPEN curParam FOR 
        SELECT * FROM EMP 
        WHERE ID = RECORD_ID; 
END;
```

Then I've imported them into EF model and map the insert procedure like in the  linked image :

[EF Model Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7GBo.jpg)

And up to now every thing is Ok and the insert procedure works well and return the id value, but when I add any other computed columns (like in the  linked image ) I get '**Index was outside the bounds of the array**' exception

[EF Model which cause exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npTpp.png)

**Exception Details:**

**StackTrace**

```
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.FunctionUpdateCommand.Execute(Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
```

**Source**

```
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess
```

Comment: It seems like problems related to caching the metadata. As discussed in the [link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4119347)